# Date is not showing

Tags: html, laravel

I want to take date from form but it is picking today date

tried but it is showing today date

app.blade.php

```
<input type = "date">
```

controller

```
$event->when=$request['date']
```

database

```
$table->date('when');
```

I want to display date according to his selected date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass data via request you have to fill the name attribute on the input, not the type.

Like this:

```
<input type="date" name="date">
```

Then, you can access it via request('date')

Comment: Sorry @BenM, when I started answering your answer wasn't showign yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your field does not have a `name` attribute. You should add one into `app.blade.php`:

```
<input type="date" name="date" />
```